# R - Read specific columns from XLSX

Tags: r, excel

This seems like a silly question, but I really could not find a solution! I need to read only specific columns from an Excel file. **The file have multiple sheets with different number of columns, but the ones I need to read will be there.** I can do this for csv files, but not for excel! This is my present code, which reads the first 14 columns (but the columns I need might not always be in the first 14). I can't just read them all as `rbind` will throw an error citing row mismatch (different number of rows in the sheets).

EDIT: I solved this by omitting the `col_types` parameter, it worked as sheets with different column numbers only had column headers. Still, this is no way a robust solution, so I hope someone can do a better job than me.

```
INV <- lapply(sheets, function(X) read_excel("./Inventory.xlsx", sheet = X, col_types = c(rep("text", 14))))
names(INV) <- sheets
INV <- do.call("rbind", INV)
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
INV <- lapply(FILES[grepl("Inventory", FILES)],
                function(n) read_csv(file=paste0(n), col_types=cols_only(DIVISION="c",
                                                                         DEPARTMENT="i",
                                                                         ITEM_ID="c",
                                                                         DESCRIPTION="c",
                                                                         UNIT_QTY="i",
                                                                         COMP_UNIT_QTY="i",
                                                                         REGION="c",
                                                                         LOCATION_TYPE="c",
                                                                         ZONE="c",
                                                                         LOCATION_ID="c",
                                                                         ATS_IND="c",
                                                                         CONTAINER_ID="c",
                                                                         STATUS="c",
                                                                         TROUBLE_CODES="c")))
```

But, for an Excel file. I tried using `read.xlsx` from `openxlsx` and `read_excel` from `readxl`, but nneither supported doing this. There must be some other way. Don't worry about column types, I am fine with all as characters.

I would very much appreciate if this can be done using `readxl` or `openxlsx`.

Comment: are you trying to select columns by name?

Comment: yes. because corresponding column numbers are different.

Comment: you could do this to change all of a data.frame to `chr` types, `as.data.frame(apply(mtcars, 2, function(x){as.character(x)}))`

Comment: and select the columns of interest with a vector of wanted columns names calles `my_cols` , `mtcars[names(mtcars) %in% my_cols]`

Comment: But this is possible only after I am past `rbind`. I was previously doing this. A sudden change in the data structure made me rewrite the code for better adaptability. I need to select the columns while reading the dataset.

Comment: wrap the reading, converting and selecting into a function designed to handle one xlsx file, then `lapply` that function to every xlsx file then `rbind` at the end

Comment: I have sheets in one excel. But your solution is doable still. Read, convert and select sheet by sheet using function and then `lapply`. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162238/discussion-between-arani-and-nate).